# Transform iterative function to recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration

I was having a discussion with a coworker about how to transform the following iterative function into a strictly recursive function. We know that all iterative functions can be transformed into recursive functions; however, my coworker remembered that this particular implementation used only three parameters. We can't re-solve this problem. Are we remembering incorrectly? Or are we missing something simple?

```
void iterative_function (char a, char b, int width) {
  int i = width;
  while (i > 0) {
    cout << string(i, a) << string(width-i, b) << endl;
    i -= 2;
  }
  i = width % 2;
  while (i <= width) {
    cout << string(i, a) << string(width-i, b) << endl;
    i += 2;
  }
}
```

Where the output looks something like below when called like `iterative_function('X', '-', 5)`.

```
XXXXX
XXX--
X----
XXX--
XXXXX
```

**EDIT:** Here is a small skeleton of what the recursive version might look like:

```
void recursive_function (char a, char b, int width) {
  if (width > -1) {
    cout << string(width, a) << endl;
    recursive(a, b, width - 2);
    cout << string(width, a) << endl;
  }
}
```

Except the problem here is filling the right side out with, say, hyphens.

Comment: Low hanging fruit: Use two recursive functions and use the stack to replace the role `i` is playing.

Comment: How are you going to keep track of the total width? It's easy to solve if you only have to print one side of the function, but more difficult when you need to fill the other side with hyphens in this example.

Comment: @tekknolagi try build a state machine to match valid output strings in the general case. I'm pretty sure you need something more general than a push down automata which is why you're having issues doing a simple transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the recursive function, I just add another `len` to your function you can see in [here](http://ideone.com/54YrHk), that its output is exactly like the output of your code [here](http://ideone.com/InMMvv).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void i_f(char a, char b, int width,int len) {

  if(len <0 || width < 0)
    return;
  cout <<string(width, a) << string(len, b) << endl;
  i_f(a,b,width-2,len+2);
  cout <<string(width, a) << string(len, b) << endl;
}

int main() {
    i_f('X', '-', 5,0);
    return 0;
}
```

your code output:

```
XXXXX
XXX--
X----
X----
XXX--
XXXXX
```

my code output:

```
XXXXX
XXX--
X----
X----
XXX--
XXXXX
```

**P.S** After I posted my answer I saw your edit, although you edited your question 10 minutes before my answer, and I can see that you choose a path like my answer yourself.

Comment: The idea, though, is to get the function to work with the same amount of parameters. It's trivial if we add another.

Comment: @tekknolagi just give me some time, I'll edit my answer to what you want.

Comment: Take all the time you like! No worries.

Comment: @tekknolagi in the mean time, edit your question, the output is wrong in your question :D

Comment: Original program output 5 rows, your answer program outputs 6; but was a change made to the original? How many rows are desired?

Comment: @Marichyasana Original program output 6 rows, I think it is mistake that tekknolagi didnt copy one row there, just run the original program and you will see that it output 6 rows not 5 rows

Comment: Just make len default, then you can call it with 3 parameters as before

Comment: @OMGtechy I dont get it

Comment: @tekknolagi yes I was trying to create program like what you want, but I left it :D

Comment: Ok ignoring my wrong program (which ideally would provide the output given), do you have a solution?

Comment: @tekknolagi no unfortunately, I think it is not possible :|